# Retrieving a host component's FormGroup variable from a directive without passing it as an attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have the following component:

```ts
@Component({
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html'
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  signupForm: FormGroup; //Notice the FormGroup instance variable
  submitted = false; //Also notice the submitted variable
  ...
```

which uses a custom `feedbackClasses` directive as follows (from `SignupComponent` template):

```ts
<div class="form-group" [feedbackClasses]="signupForm" [control]="'firstName'" [submitted]="submitted">
```

Here is the definition for the directive:

```ts
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, DoCheck} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({selector: '[feedbackClasses]'})
export class FeedbackClassesDirective implements DoCheck {

  @Input('feedbackClasses') formGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input('control') controlPath: string; //I would like to avoid passing this as an attribute
  @Input('submitted') submitted: boolean;//Same thing here

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    const control: AbstractControl = this.formGroup.get(this.controlPath);
    if (control && this.submitted) {
      this.applyClasses(control.invalid);
    }
  }

  private applyClasses(inError: boolean) {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'has-success', !inError);
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'has-danger', inError);
  }

}
```

The issue I have is that each time I want to use this directive, I have to pass in the corresponding `FormGroup` and the `boolean` that indicates whether or not the form has been submitted.

Is there a way to retrieve the `FormGroup` and the `boolean` directly from the directive without using attributes? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the component where the directive is applied to.
For this the directive can only be applied to one type of component.

```ts
@Directive({selector: '[feedbackClasses]'})
export class FeedbackClassesDirective implements DoCheck {

  @Input('feedbackClasses') formGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input('control') controlPath: string; //I would like to avoid passing this as an attribute
  @Input('submitted') submitted: boolean;//Same thing here

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, 
              private renderer: Renderer, 
              private signUpComponent: SignupComponent) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.signUpComponent.signUpForm);
    console.log(signUpComponent.submitted); // probably not set yet
  }
}
```

Or you can provide a shared service on the components that should support the directive and inject it

```ts
@Injectable()
export class FormStatusService {
  signupForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false; // better use an BehaviorSubject
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html':
  providers: [FormStatusService]
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  //signupForm: FormGroup; //Notice the FormGroup instance variable
  //submitted = false; //Also notice the submitted variable

  constructor(private formStatus:FormStatusService) {
    // access shared service to read and write values
  }
  ...
}
```

```ts
@Directive({selector: '[feedbackClasses]'})
export class FeedbackClassesDirective implements DoCheck {

//  @Input('feedbackClasses') formGroup: FormGroup;
//  @Input('control') controlPath: string; //I would like to avoid passing this as an attribute
  // @Input('submitted') submitted: boolean;//Same thing here

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, 
              private renderer: Renderer,
              private signUpComponent: FormStatusService) {
    // access shared service to read and write values
  }
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thanks Günter, Can you please explain why a `BehaviorSubject` would help? Also, did you forget to inject the `FormStatusService` within the constructor of the directive?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, added the service to the constructor (got distracted ;-) ). A `Subject` or `Observable` allows to push-notify, instead of polling. A `BehaviorSubject` sends the last emitted value immediately to new subscribers. This helps for example avoiding some timing problems when two classes are created one after the other and one emits an event in the constructor while the other class has yet to be created and will miss that initial event because it only subscribes after the value was emitted. (just one example where it's convenient).

Comment: Ummm... I am still unclear what to inject into the directive: you injected the `signupComponent` which creates coupling between the directive (meant to be used on many components) and the signup Component. Did you mean to inject the `FormStatusService` into the directive?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Need some more coffee it seems :-/

Comment: Can I reuse the same `FormStatusService` class across all my components that use the directive (it seems that would be problematic because it is a singleton...) or do I need as many `xxFormStatusService` classes as there are components?

Comment: By the way I have a dozen such components (using a FormGroup and the custom directive).

Comment: No, if you provide it in `@Component(...)`, you will get a new service instance for each component instance - only available to itself and its children. If a child component also provides this service, this instance will be used for its children. Therefore you should be safe even when this kind of components/directives are nested.

Comment: Yes I like the way angular 2 allows for local-scoped dependency injection through local providers and the `FormStatusService`  nicely encapsulate state. Thanks a lot again.